# Figure out which Quartz trigger triggered job

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to tell which trigger is the one the kicked the job off?  I've got a Grails app and I'm using the quartz plugin to schedule some jobs, but I'd like to be able to do just a bit different things depending on which trigger kicked off the job...

```
class MyJob {

  static triggers = {
     cron name: 'noonTrigger', cronExpression: '0 0 12 * * ? *'//12:00 PM every day
     cron name: 'twoPMTrigger', cronExpression: '0 0 14 * * ? *'//2:00 PM every day
  }

  def execute(){
     if(noonTrigger)
        ...
     else if(twoPMTrigger)
        ...
     else
        ...//kicked off from controller
  }
}
```

Is there a way to tell in the execute which trigger kicked this off?  Or maybe even a way to say this job wasn't kicked off by a trigger but was kicked off from some controller code or something like that?

EDIT:
Based off of Joshua Moore's info, the code looks like this:

```
def execute(context){ 
  if(context.trigger.key.name == 'noonTrigger'){
    ...
  }...
  ...
}
```

Works like a champ.  From a controller it seems the name is randomly(?) generated but this still works fine as well:

```
class MyController{
  def myMethod(){
    MyJob.triggerNow([:])
  }
}
```

Comment: The name is determined by org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.newTriggerId which does base the name on a random value:

private String newTriggerId() {
  long r = random.nextLong();
  if (r < 0) {
    r = -r;
  }
  return "MT_" + Long.toString(r, 30 + (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 7)); 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grails Quartz plugin allows you to define your execute method with a single parameter for the JobExecutionContext (e.g. def execute(context)). From the JobExecutionContext you can use getTrigger() to find the trigger used to fire the job. Take a look at the API docs for
[JobExecutionContext](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html) for more information.